If integrated tail $F_I$ is subexponential, is $F$ also subexponential?
I’m currently reading Non-Life Insurance Mathematics by Thomas Mikosch and in chapter 4 on Ruin theory there is constant distinction between light and heavy-tailed distributions (as there should be) but when the author provides the asymptotic behavior of ruin probability for heavy tailed distributions as the inital reserve $u \to \infty$ (page 174-176). He states (in theorem 4.2.14) that the integrated tail of claim size distribution is subexponential, does that indicate that the claims themselves have a subexponential/heavy tailed distribution? If not, what does it tell us about the distribution of claim size? I'll state the theorem bellow.
$\textbf{Theorem 4.2.14} $ (Ruin probability when integrated claim size distribution is subexponential) Assume the Cramér-Lunberg model with $E(X_1) < \infty$ and NPC. In addition assume that the claim sizes $X_i$ have a density and that the integrated claim size distibution $F_{X_1, I}$ is subexponential. Then the ruin probability $\psi(u)$ satisfies the asymptotic relationship
$$
\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\psi(u)}{1 - F_{X_1, I}(u)} = \frac{1}{\rho}
$$
Edit: To clarify the question, the main thing that I dont understand is: If $F_I$ is subexponential, does that indicate that $F$ is also subexponential? Also, the integrated tail distribution of a positive random variable $X$ is given by
$$
F_{X, I}(x) = \frac{1}{E(X)}\int_{0}^xP(X > t)dt.
$$

Could you define $F_{X_1, I}$ and the ruin probability to make the question self-contained?

I added the definition of integrated tail distribution, but the ruin probability is a bit too complex to include in the explanation, nor is it too relevant. The main question is about the subexponential property, everything else is more for context.

Thank you for the edit. Could you specify what exactly you mean by "the supexponential property"?

The general definition of a subexponential distribution is as follows: $$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overline{F^{*2}}(x)}{\overline{F}(x)} = 2,
$$
where $\overline{F}(x) = 1 - F(x) $ is the tail distribution function, and $ F^{*2} $is the convolution of $ F $ with itself, i.e.,
$$
F^{*2}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} F(x - y) dF(y).
$$

Other equivalent definitions exist.
